# PyMC3 - Differences in ways observations are passed to model -> difference in results?

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, pymc3

I'm trying to understand if there is any meaningful difference in the ways of passing data into a model - either aggregated or as single trials (note this will only be a sensical question for certain distributions e.g. Binomial).

Predicting *p* for a yes/no trail, using a simple model with a Binomial distribution.

What is the difference in the computation/results of the following models (if any)?

I choose the two extremes, either passing in a single trail at once (reducing to Bernoulli) or passing in the sum of the entire series of trails, to exemplify my meaning though I am interested in the difference in between these extremes also.

```
# set up constants
p_true = 0.1
N = 3000
observed = scipy.stats.bernoulli.rvs(p_true, size=N)
```

Model 1: combining all observations into a single data point

```
with pm.Model() as binomial_model1:
    p = pm.Uniform('p', lower=0, upper=1)
    observations = pm.Binomial('observations', N, p, observed=np.sum(observed))
    trace1 = pm.sample(40000)
```

Model 2: using each observation individually

```
with pm.Model() as binomial_model2:
    p = pm.Uniform('p', lower=0, upper=1)
    observations = pm.Binomial('observations', 1, p, observed=observed)
    trace2 = pm.sample(40000)
```

There is isn't any noticeable difference in the trace or posteriors in this case. I attempted to dig into the pymc3 source code to try to see how the observations were being processed but couldn't find the right part.

Possible expected answers:

- pymc3 aggregates the observations under the hood for Binomial anyway so their is no difference
- the resultant posterior surface (which is explored in the sample process) is identical in each case -> there is no meaningful/statistical difference in the two models
- there are differences in the resultant statistics because of this and that...

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting example! Your second suggestion is correct: you can actually work out the posterior analytically, and it will be distributed according to

```
Beta(sum(observed), N - sum(observed))
```

in either case.

The difference in modelling approach would show up if you used, for example, `pm.sample_ppc`, in that the first would be distributed according to `Binomial(N, p)` and the second would be `N` draws of `Binomial(1, p)`.