# Why am I getting a dimension mismatch in my PyMC3 hierarchical model?

Tags: pymc3, hierarchical-bayesian

This is essentially the "Multiple Coins from Multiple Mints / Baseball Players" example from *Doing Bayesian Data Analysis, Second Edition* (DBDA2). I believe I have PyMC3 code which is functionally equivalent, but one works and the other does not. This is with PyMC version 3.5.  In more detail,

Let's say I have the following data. Each row is an observation:

```
observations_dict = {
    'mint': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'coin': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7],
    'outcome': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
}
observations = pd.DataFrame(observations_dict)
observations
```

#### One Mint, Several Coins

The below, which implements DBDA2 Figure 9.7, runs just fine:

[image: Fig 9.7]

```
num_coins = observations['coin'].nunique()
coin_idx = observations['coin']

with pm.Model() as hierarchical_model:
    # mint is characterized by omega and kappa
    omega = pm.Beta('omega', 1., 1.)
    kappa_minus2 = pm.Gamma('kappa_minus2', 0.01, 0.01)
    kappa = pm.Deterministic('kappa', kappa_minus2 + 2)

    # each coin is described by a theta
    theta = pm.Beta('theta', alpha=omega*(kappa-2)+1, beta=(1-omega)*(kappa-2)+1, shape=num_coins)

    # define the likelihood
    y = pm.Bernoulli('y', theta[coin_idx], observed=observations['outcome'])
```

#### Many Mints, Many Coins

However, once this is turned into a hierarchical model (as seen in DBDA2 Figure 9.13):

[image: Fig 9.13]

```
num_mints = observations['mint'].nunique()
mint_idx = observations['mint']
num_coins = observations['coin'].nunique()
coin_idx = observations['coin']

with pm.Model() as hierarchical_model2:
    # Hyper parameters
    omega = pm.Beta('omega', 1, 1)
    kappa_minus2 = pm.Gamma('kappa_minus2', 0.01, 0.01)
    kappa = pm.Deterministic('kappa', kappa_minus2 + 2)

    # Parameters for mints
    omega_c = pm.Beta('omega_c',
                       omega*(kappa-2)+1, (1-omega)*(kappa-2)+1,
                       shape = num_mints)    
    kappa_c_minus2 = pm.Gamma('kappa_c_minus2',
                              0.01, 0.01,
                              shape = num_mints)
    kappa_c = pm.Deterministic('kappa_c', kappa_c_minus2 + 2)

    # Parameters for coins
    theta = pm.Beta('theta',
                     omega_c[mint_idx]*(kappa_c[mint_idx]-2)+1,
                    (1-omega_c[mint_idx])*(kappa_c[mint_idx]-2)+1,
                     shape = num_coins)

    y2 = pm.Bernoulli('y2', p=theta[coin_idx], observed=observations['outcome'])
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,) (20,)
```

as the model has 8 thetas for 8 coins but sees 20 rows of data.

However, if the data is grouped such that each line represents the final statistics of an individual coin, as with the following

```
grouped = observations.groupby(['mint', 'coin']).agg({'outcome': [np.sum, np.size]}).reset_index()
grouped.columns = ['mint', 'coin', 'heads', 'total']
```

And the final likelihood variable is changed to a Binomial, as follows

```
num_mints = grouped['mint'].nunique()
mint_idx = grouped['mint']
num_coins = grouped['coin'].nunique()
coin_idx = grouped['coin']

with pm.Model() as hierarchical_model2:
    # Hyper parameters
    omega = pm.Beta('omega', 1, 1)
    kappa_minus2 = pm.Gamma('kappa_minus2', 0.01, 0.01)
    kappa = pm.Deterministic('kappa', kappa_minus2 + 2)

    # Parameters for mints
    omega_c = pm.Beta('omega_c',
                       omega*(kappa-2)+1, (1-omega)*(kappa-2)+1,
                       shape = num_mints)    
    kappa_c_minus2 = pm.Gamma('kappa_c_minus2',
                              0.01, 0.01,
                              shape = num_mints)
    kappa_c = pm.Deterministic('kappa_c', kappa_c_minus2 + 2)

    # Parameter for coins
    theta = pm.Beta('theta',
                     omega_c[mint_idx]*(kappa_c[mint_idx]-2)+1,
                    (1-omega_c[mint_idx])*(kappa_c[mint_idx]-2)+1,
                     shape = num_coins)

    y2 = pm.Binomial('y2', n=grouped['total'], p=theta, observed=grouped['heads'])
```

Everything works. Now, the latter form is more efficient and generally preferred, but I believe the former should work as well. So I believe this is primarily a PyMC3 issue (or even more likely, a user error).

To quote DBDA Edition 1,

> "The BUGS model uses a binomial likelihood distribution for total
>   correct, instead of using the Bernoulli distribution for individual
>   trials. This use of the binomial is just a convenience for shortening
>   the program. If the data were specified as trial-by-trial outcomes
>   instead of as total correct, then the model could include a
>   trial-by-trial loop and use a Bernoulli likelihood function"

What bothers me is that in the very first example (One Mint, Several Coins), it looks like PyMC3 can handle individual observations instead of aggregated observations just fine. So I believe the first form should work, but doesn't.

#### Code

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JWarmenhoven/DBDA-python/blob/master/Notebooks/Chapter%209.ipynb

#### References

[PyMC3 - Differences in ways observations are passed to model -> difference in results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952953/pymc3-differences-in-ways-observations-are-passed-to-model-difference-in-re)

https://discourse.pymc.io/t/pymc3-differences-in-ways-observations-are-passed-to-model-difference-in-results/501

http://www.databozo.com/deep-in-the-weeds-complex-hierarchical-models-in-pymc3

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157521/is-this-correct-hierarchical-bernoulli-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of `mint_idx` was 20 (one for each observation), but it should have been 8 (one for each coin).

Working answer, notice the `mint_idx` recalculation (rest remains the same):

```
grouped = observations.groupby(['mint', 'coin']).agg({'outcome': [np.sum, np.size]}).reset_index()
grouped.columns = ['mint', 'coin', 'heads', 'total']

num_mints = grouped['mint'].nunique()
mint_idx = grouped['mint']
num_coins = observations['coin'].nunique()
coin_idx = observations['coin']

with pm.Model() as hierarchical_model2:
    # Hyper parameters
    omega = pm.Beta('omega', 1, 1)
    kappa_minus2 = pm.Gamma('kappa_minus2', 0.01, 0.01)
    kappa = pm.Deterministic('kappa', kappa_minus2 + 2)

    # Parameters for mints
    omega_c = pm.Beta('omega_c',
                       omega*(kappa-2)+1, (1-omega)*(kappa-2)+1,
                       shape = num_mints)    
    kappa_c_minus2 = pm.Gamma('kappa_c_minus2',
                              0.01, 0.01,
                              shape = num_mints)
    kappa_c = pm.Deterministic('kappa_c', kappa_c_minus2 + 2)

    # Parameters for coins
    theta = pm.Beta('theta',
                     omega_c[mint_idx]*(kappa_c[mint_idx]-2)+1,
                    (1-omega_c[mint_idx])*(kappa_c[mint_idx]-2)+1,
                     shape = num_coins)

    y2 = pm.Bernoulli('y2', p=theta[coin_idx], observed=observations['outcome'])
```

Many thanks to @junpenglao!!
https://discourse.pymc.io/t/why-cant-i-use-a-bernoulli-as-a-likelihood-variable-in-a-hierarchical-model-in-pymc3/2022/2